# Set Dropdown list razor value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, html-select

Im trying to assign the value selected on my 'Razor Dropdown List' into my Input Field but im not getting any result from my javascript

This is my Drodown lsit:

```
      <input type="text" name="txtInput" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" name="test" value="enter"/>   
      @Html.DropDownList("Fechas", "Todas")
```

This is my Javascript:

```js
 $("#Fechas").live("change", function () {
                        $("#txtInput").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
                    })
```

How can i get the input to get the value of the dropdown list each time a user pics something from my dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
$(function(){
   $('select[name="Fechas"]').on("change", function () {
     $('input[name="txtInput"]').val($(this).val());
   });

});
```

Comment: you need to find the element by name

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is your solution and how does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `live()` is deprecated from version 1.7 onwards. Use `on` to attach event handlers instead of `live()`

The below code should work fine.

```
$(function(){

   $("#Fechas").on("change", function () {
     $("#txtInput").val($(this).val());
   });

});
```

Comment: i tryed your function but stil i cant asign the dropdown value to my input, it always stay blanck

Comment: Do you have any script errors in your page ? Do you have an input with Id txtInput ?

Comment: yes my input is on my question like this : <input type="text" name="txtInput" value=""/> i dont have any script errors

Comment: It should work fine if you do not have any other script errors http://jsbin.com/pahuyipibo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it may be because im using a html.dropdownlist instead of <select>?

Comment: Does not matter as long as it generates the correct HTML markup with the  Id  `Fechas`. Check the js bin i posted in prev comment.

Comment: i checked you jsbin but in my script section it doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: Did you include the script properly. Can you put a console.log before and after the line `$("#Fechas").on("change", function () {` and see whether you get a line in console